# AppDelegate.swift and RESideMenu - Trouble InitContentViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, initialization, swift

I'm trying to use [RESideMenu](https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu) in my Swift app.  I have used [RESideMenu](https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu) before when I wrote my app in Objective-C.  This is what I wrote (and it works perfectly):

```
        leftSideMenuViewController *leftMenuViewController = [[leftSideMenuViewController alloc] init];
        rightSideMenuViewController *rightMenuViewController = [[rightSideMenuViewController alloc] init];

// This is what I am struggling to translate in particular:

    RESideMenu *sideMenuViewController = [[RESideMenu alloc] initWithContentViewController:navigationController
    leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController
    rightMenuViewController:rightMenuViewController];
    sideMenuViewController.menuPreferredStatusBarStyle = 1;

//
```

I'm having trouble converting it to Swift.  (I have a `leftSideMenuViewController.swift` and `rightSideMenuViewController.swift`).  I have tried this so far:

```
    let leftMenuViewController: leftSideMenuViewController!
    let rightMenuViewController: rightSideMenuViewController!

    let sideMenuViewController: RESideMenu!
    leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController
    rightMenuViewController:rightMenuViewController

    sideMenuViewController.menuPrefferedStatusBarStyle = 1
```

Could anybody help me out, please?  I read around on SO about using ! to force unwrap, so I force-unwrapped leftSideMenuViewController.

I also read about a bridging-header, in which I imported `RESideMenu.h` correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: please tell us what behaviour you're getting: what happens when you run the app? does it build? any errors?

Answer (score 1):

In RootViewController

```
self.contentViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("contentViewController") as UIViewController
  self.leftMenuViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("leftMenuViewController") as UIViewController
  self.leftMenuViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("rightMenuViewController") as UIViewController

  self.menuPreferredStatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
```

By the way, 'let' is for assigning constant, 'var' is for variable.
If you want to declare a variable and assign it later, you should use 'var' instead of 'let'

In XCode, after you type '.' wait for a while and see what options you have. That's must helpful in converting object-C to swift.

I convert from the example with storyboard. Seems like you are trying to convert from the example without storyboard.

Comment: I think it should be self.menuPreferredStatusBarStyle = .LightContent;